# Inconsistent argument passing mode

Tags: ada

Consider the following code (which compile with GCC 4.7.4):

```
procedure Main is
    procedure Sub_Proc(N : in out Integer) is
        M : Integer;
    begin
        M := N;
    end;
    procedure Proc(N : out Integer) is
    begin
        Sub_Proc(N);
    end;

    N : Integer;
begin
    Proc(N);
end Main;
```

The procedure `Proc` is supposed to ensure that the argument `N` which is an *out argument* will never be read inside his body. But it passes this argument to a procedure `Sub_Proc` which takes an *in out argument*, so potentially the previous argument will be read inside this procedure whereas the calling procedure ensured the opposite.

Is it a GCC bug or an Ada standard specificity ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You’ll have received a warning on the `Sub_Proc(N);` call: `"N" may be referenced before it has a value`. So the compiler was trying to help!

In [Ada 83](http://archive.adaic.com/standards/83lrm/html/lrm-06-04.html), your program would have been illegal: 6.4.1(3) says "for the mode in out, the variable must not be a formal parameter of mode out”. Indeed, using `-gnat83`, and after a minor rearrangement of the code to allow it to compile, the equivalent to the above warning is the error `(Ada 83) illegal reading of out parameter`.

In [Ada 95](http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/95lrm/ARM_HTML/RM-6-4-1.html) and [Ada 2012](http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/12rm/html/RM-6-4-1.html#p12) it *is* OK to read the value of an `out` parameter after it has been assigned; in ARM95 6.4.1(15) we find that the value starts out uninitialized (as indicated by the warning message noted above), so using it is a Bad Idea.

So the answer is, GNAT’s behaviour conforms with the standard.